# How to download network image in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a simple wallpaper app with Api by watching tutorials on YouTube. But in the last stage, I can't save the image from the URL in the android simulator. Can you guys help me with how can I do this work?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class ImageView extends StatefulWidget {
  final String imageUrl;
  ImageView({@required this.imageUrl});
  @override
  _ImageViewState createState() => _ImageViewState();}
class _ImageViewState extends State<ImageView> {
  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      Hero(
        tag: widget.imageUrl,
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Image.network(
            widget.imageUrl,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),

//the buttons is here
      Container(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            //wallpaper download button
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {},
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
                      height: 55,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color(0xff1c1b1b).withOpacity(0.8),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                      )),
                  Container(
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 8),
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                      height: 55,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            width: 1,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                            Colors.blueGrey[100],
                            Colors.grey[900],
                          ])),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'Set Wallpaper',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 5),
                          Text(
                            'Image wil be save in gallery',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 10,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      )),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 16),
            //for closeing the showing wallpaper
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              child: Text(
                'Cancel',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.amber,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 50)
          ],
        ),
      )
    ],
   ),
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Step 1: To save image to gallery, add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` to `AndroidManifest.xml` 
Step 2: Request permission with `permission_handler` 
Step 3: Download file with `flutter_cache_manager`'s `DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(widget.imageUrl)` 
Step 4: Save to gallery with `image_gallery_saver`'s `ImageGallerySaver.saveFile(file.path)` 
Step 5: Directly set wall paper with `wallpaper_manager`'s  `WallpaperManager.setWallpaperFromFile(file.path, WallpaperManager.HOME_SCREEN)`

code snippet

```
_requestPermission() async {
    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
      Permission.storage,
    ].request();

    final info = statuses[Permission.storage].toString();
    print(info);
  }
...  
GestureDetector(
          onTap: () async {
            File file = await DefaultCacheManager()
                .getSingleFile(widget.imageUrl);
            print(file.path);
            final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveFile(file.path);
            print("gallerysaver result $result");

            String resultWall =
                await WallpaperManager.setWallpaperFromFile(
                    file.path, WallpaperManager.HOME_SCREEN);

            print("resultWall $resultWall");
          },
```

working demo

[image]

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_cache_manager/flutter_cache_manager.dart';
import 'package:wallpaper_manager/wallpaper_manager.dart';
import 'package:image_gallery_saver/image_gallery_saver.dart';

class ImageView extends StatefulWidget {
  final String imageUrl;
  ImageView({@required this.imageUrl});
  @override
  _ImageViewState createState() => _ImageViewState();
}

class _ImageViewState extends State<ImageView> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _requestPermission();
  }

  _requestPermission() async {
    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
      Permission.storage,
    ].request();

    final info = statuses[Permission.storage].toString();
    print(info);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Hero(
            tag: widget.imageUrl,
            child: Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Image.network(
                widget.imageUrl,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),

//the buttons is here
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                //wallpaper download button
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () async {
                    File file = await DefaultCacheManager()
                        .getSingleFile(widget.imageUrl);
                    print(file.path);
                    final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveFile(file.path);
                    print("gallerysaver result $result");

                    String resultWall =
                        await WallpaperManager.setWallpaperFromFile(
                            file.path, WallpaperManager.HOME_SCREEN);

                    print("resultWall $resultWall");
                  },
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                          height: 55,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Color(0xff1c1b1b).withOpacity(0.8),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          )),
                      Container(
                          padding:
                              EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 8),
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                          height: 55,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                width: 1,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                              gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                                Colors.blueGrey[100],
                                Colors.grey[900],
                              ])),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Set Wallpaper',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 5),
                              Text(
                                'Image wil be save in gallery',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 10,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          )),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16),
                //for closeing the showing wallpaper
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                  child: Text(
                    'Cancel',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.amber,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 50)
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => ImageView(
                              imageUrl: "https://picsum.photos/250?image=9")),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Text('To set wall paper')),
            ])));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying.
I did that you have sad but this error showing can you help me out.
Here is the github repo https://github.com/Monzim/m_wallpaper
E/flutter ( 4459): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method requestPermissions on channel flutter.baseflow.com/permissions/methods)

Comment: your github code did not update to latest code. so I can not check your error. after add related package to pubspec.yaml, you can restart your app. because hot restart sometimes won't work.

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks.

Comment: you can also try flutter clean if error persist.

Comment: Chunhunghan thank you so much for replying again. I'm relay sorry for forgot to upload the latest code. I pushed it recently. Can you please see it again it will be really helpful for me.
I have also added those dependencies previously.
http: ^0.12.2
  cached_network_image: ^2.4.1
  flutter_cache_manager: ^2.0.0
  permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1
  image_gallery_saver: ^1.6.7
  wallpaper_manager: ^1.0.10

Comment: your data/data.dart did not exist. and apiKey is empty. did you encounter any error. Need to reproduce your issue without your apiKey. Could you post your reproduce code to new question? Thanks.

Comment: All the code that you told me to add I added those code here:https://github.com/Monzim/m_wallpaper/blob/main/lib/views/image_view.dart
and for Api problem I added a new file in https://github.com/Monzim/m_wallpaper/blob/main/lib/read_it/instruction_test.dart
Just uncomment those code and add a api code. copy all those code and paste it in "lib/data/" as data.dart name.
then it will work.
Thank you so much it will be very for helpful me if you help me to solve it.